# Sri Vishnu Sahasranama bhashyam

Tags: vishnu-sahasranama

I have been reciting Sri Vishnu sahasranama for a few months now. There are a lot of translations and explanations to the great Sri Vishnu sahasranama but I haven't come across one that fills my heart with lot of love and happiness for the Lord. For every nama, different authors interpret differently, that is greatness of each nama.. Can you please suggest a great reading of the namas?

Comment: Sri Parashara Bhattar - Bhagavath Guna Darpanam

Answer (score 4):

Adi Shankaracharya has written a commentary on the Vishnu Sahasranama. You can read it [here](https://archive.org/details/Vishnu.Sahasranama.with.the.Bhasya.of.Sankaracharya).

Sri Baladev Vidyabhusana has written another commentary from the Achintya Bhedabheda school of Vedanta. You can read it [here](http://ebooks.iskcondesiretree.com/pdf/Gaudiya_Books%20/Baladeva_Vidyabhusana/Baladeva_Vidyabhusana_Vishnu_Sahasra_Nama.pdf).